Dynamic Factors with Statsmodels in Python
I am fitting a linear gaussian state space model in python using statsmodels.DynamicFactorMQ. It is giving me back only the model summary, but I want to extract the estimated AR(1) transition matrix for the latent factors, the observation matrix from the observation equation, and the covariance matrices for the AR(1) error term and the observation error term. Does anyone know how to do this? the documentation is quite unclear.
